# Include Boost C++ library in android

Tags: android, c++, boost, java-native-interface

I have been trying to marry Boost and android on windows for long time and tried lot of approaches but still no luck. I want to make a sample program using Boost library in android. I am following this tutorial [here.](http://www.codexperiments.com/android/2011/05/tips-tricks-building-boost-with-ndk-r5/)

As this tutorial suggested i have kept my Boost lib in ****(Android NDK)\sources\boost_1_44_0**** compiled it successfully.

Then i made an **Android.mk** file inside **sources/boost_1_44_0** and made the entry of each library which i want to use. In this case lib. file is **libboost_date_time-gcc-mt-s-1_44.a** available in **boost_1_44_0/android/lib/**
Here is the content of **Android.mk** file.

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= boost_date
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= boost_1_44_0/android/lib/libboost_date_time-gcc-mt-s-1_44.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Now the next step is to make an **Android.mk** file in my project directory, inside **jni** folder.(this is to create a shared library.). Here are its contents.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
 include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# Here we give our module name and source file(s)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -ldl
LOCAL_MODULE    := ndkfoo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ndkfoo.cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := boost_date
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
$(call import-module,boost_1_44_0)
```

Here is the Application.mk file placed on the same location, inside **jni** folder. Contents of Application.mk file are as follows:

```
APP_STL      = gnustl_static #(or APP_STL = stlport_static as required)
APP_CPPFLAGS = -fexceptions
```

And finally here is my **ndkfoo.cpp** file

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

using namespace boost::gregorian;

void Java_com_ndkfoo_NdkfooActivity_invokeNativeFunction(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis) {
    date weekstart(2002,Feb,1);

}
```

this program might be incorrect but the problem is that it does not recognize any boost  headers or function. and i always get compilation error.

Is there something i am missing or doing incorrectly? Any help would be really appreciated.

**EDIT:**   *This question contains everything you would need to include Boost library in android. For more tips look at my answer below. Hopefully this would also work for you.*

Thanks.

Comment: For one thing: your path is slightly different: in the tutorial the author has extracted to $ANDROID_NDK/sources/boost. Not sure if that makes a difference. The author's path to the lib begins with *android/..*, yours with *boost_1_44_0/android/..*. I would first try follow the tutorial exactly and see if that resolves your issues.

Comment: ya true, but i think it might not make any difference.

Comment: knock knock anybody's there? please help me.....

Comment: Have you tried to use "ndk-build V=1" to see if the includes are right? That log might gives us more clues.

Comment: hi! @paul did you try to run bjam or b2. it is a tool to compile boost. look at this link. http://www.codexperiments.com/android/2011/05/tips-tricks-building-boost-with-ndk-r5/ i have already mentioned this link in my post.

Comment: @N-JOY Yeah, I managed to compile bjam first. But when I tried to compile boost library. it's giving me unknown in module path.

Comment: have you set the NDK path in user_config.jam

Comment: Yes, I followed instruction of the article.

Comment: okk then try installing mingW compiler(gcc compiler) and then set path in enviromental variables or copy gcc.exe to cygwin's bin folder.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5339/discussion-between-n-joy-and-paul)

Comment: Thanks for your help with my problem and also appreciate your description of the problem with include file. Now I can use boost in my app.

Comment: welcome and N_JOY BOOST.

Comment: I am trying to resolve the same issues as the question. It seems how they resolved it was lost in the "continue this discussion in chat" link. Can some one throw some light on how i could use boost with Android please. I am having an issues with include<boost/*.h>. Please help

Comment: Also try and look at the suggestions mentioned in answer

Comment: I'm getting error in compile time when I include boost header: 'struct in6_addr' has no member named 's6_addr' . Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My question contained almost complete steps for including BOOST library in Android. But still there are some important points you should remember while working with this.

- Delete auto generated `obj` and `lib`s folder Each time before you compile your native code.
- If you are going to write your native code in C++, add `LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cpp` to your Android.mk(`jni/Android.mk`) file.
- if you are going to code in C++, put your all cpp code inside `extern "C" {}`.

  `extern C {       /*cpp code*/      }`