# How to add static library built from another NDK project along with headers?

Tags: android-ndk

I have two separate projects and one project is used for building Boost library and the other one makes calls from the built boost library.

Boost project compiles fine and produces libboost.a file. What I want to achieve is to add this library to my other NDK project and make calls to Boost from it. I have looked around quite much and almost all solutions consists of copying the built library to the main project directory along with header files but I don't want to move files around all the time. Is there any other decent way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your Boost library header files path to your Android.mk file with something like the following:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ../MyBoostLib/inc
```

You can add your Boost library to your Android.mk file with something like the following:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += ../MyBoostLib/obj/local/armeabi/libMyBoostLib.a
```

As long as the relationship between the two project locations remains the same, you should be OK.

Comment: The problem is that, the projects are in different directories as well as the header files as you would expect. I suppose there is no way to access to any other directory other than the jni directory of the project?

Comment: You can access any directory you want. You can put in absolute paths if necessary or multiple ../'s.

Comment: Tried that one actually. 

LIB_LOC := $(abspath $(LOCAL_PATH)/../..)
LOCAL_LDLIBS += $(LIB_LOC)/libboost.a

returns "target pattern contains no '%'" error.

Comment: Not sure why you need to use abspath in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/675fe49445e65ba44d91f4d85ed9b4d5b5ff6745/docs/IMPORT-MODULE.TXT for discussion, and see [Include Boost C++ library in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885384/include-boost-c-library-in-android) for boost-specific instructions.