# c++ Android NDK and include issues

Tags: android-ndk

I am getting into building c++ modules for my apps. I cannot get boost or system to work.

I do the following:

```
#include <boost>
```

or

```
#include <system>
```

and BOTH things result in "boost no such file or directory" and "system no such file or directory.

I cannot begin to list the things I have attempted because the list is way too long. I have followed multiple links leading me to lots of things. But nothing seems to work. If I can get `#include <system>` to work then I won't need boost. I would prefer to get `#include <system>` working for that will allow me to execute command line commands inside my module.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you include `stlport_static` to the project. I think "APP_STL:=stlport_static" must be in Application.mk file.

Did you see these links:

http://stoflru.org/questions/23783680/android-ndk-include-boost-library

[Include Boost C++ library in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885384/include-boost-c-library-in-android)

[Android NDK: Including boost c++ library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376832/android-ndk-including-boost-c-library)

Comment: Yes I have seen the last one. I do not recall from memory if I included that `stlport_static` in the Application.mk file. I know I have the `APP_STL:=` inside the Application.mk file but can't recall without looking at it what I referenced. Once I get home I will look through my build setup and go through those links and see if I can get it working. Thanks so much! Hope one of them works!